# How to set a configuration property when using fluent nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In particular, I'd like to set `current_session_context_class`. I know how to do it in hibernate.cfg.xml, but is it possible at all with pure fluent configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the method `ExposeConfiguration` on a `FluentConfiguration` instance, to access the original NHibernate `Configuration` object.

Then, you'll have access to the `Properties` property, and you will be able to add the `current_session_context_class` one.

Here is a the pseudo-code:

```
Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory)
   .ExposeConfiguration(c =>
                        {
                          c.Properties.Add("current_session_context_class", 
                                           typeof(YourType).FullName);
                        })
   //.AddMapping, etc.
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when I call GetCurrentSession it still throws an exception telling me to set the property.

Comment: Well, my answer is 2 years old now, so it doesn't surprise me that much. Unfortunately, I'm no longer using FluentNHibernate and I'm not sure I can update my answer anytime soon...

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work for me either, I'm having a similar problem with FlushMode, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260763/nhibernate-fluently-configure-default-flush-mode-for-session-sessionfactory/52289646#52289646